# Any tips on pinpointing Windows 7 instability?

Tags: windows-7, windows, malware

Ever since I removed malware my Windows 7 computer has been unstable. The mouse and keyboard randomly stop working for a few seconds and sometimes the system freezes all together. The behaviour is very random but I often have a 10 minutes of good use after the computer is first started. The behaviour started happening after I removed some malware, but also around the same time I updated the graphics card driver and updated to the latest version of Firefox. Part of the malware removal process included updating plugins etc. and I'm wondering if one plugin broke something. Is there anyway I can pinpoint it? I ran `chckdsk` and it said it repaired something's. I also ran `sfc /scannow` and have its log.

It's almost as if I need to keep a log of all programs I ran since booting the computer and trying to find a common one each time Windows freezes up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to pinpoint defects is to do only *one change at a time* and then test it.

In this case you could try;

- removing firefox
- re-installing the old graphics driver

Test after each action to see if it solves the problem.

Sometimes it can be very difficult to eradicate a piece of malware. So it is often safer to wipe the disk and restore a previsouly made backup (you have those, right?)

If you don't have backups, the best way is to make a backup of all your data, wipe the disk and re-install windows, your data and all applications. When that is done and doesn't exhibit a problem, make sure to get a backup! Restoring a backup is generally faster and less effort than installing the OS and all apps again.

**Edit:**
If you suspect firefox, remove all of it including plug-ins and add-ons (that means also removing adobe's flash player) and reboot the computer. If the problem hasn't returned after an hour or so of normal use, firefox or one of its plugins/add-ons was the problem.

The next step is to re-install the latest version of firefox without any plug-ins or add-ons. If that exhibits the problem within an hour or so, submit a bug report to mozilla.

If mozilla itself is OK, install your favorite add-ons and plug-ins one at a time and see if the problem returns.

Comment: I think I found it's Firefox causing the instability but how can I be sure? I can try not using it but for how long?

Comment: @Celeritas: see updated answer.